# How to get Firestore collection list then match with specific field for security rule

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

How to check if `exists` firestore collection document filtering using other field instead of uid for the security rule

Here is my code

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /users/{users} {

    // I need to check email if exist

      allow read, write : exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/email/$(request.data.email))
    }

  }
}
```

any suggestions for this ?

Comment: Have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents. You need to use `if exists()` or `if get()`. Note that these unctions both expect fully specified document paths. From your question it is not 100% clear what would be the path of the document you will check.

Comment: Can you indicate the exact path of the document that contains the user email. In particular, what is the ID of this document? The user's UID? The email (escaped)? Another value?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code for the query that should be allowed by this rule.  Note that [security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters).

Answer (score 0):

In Simple way

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /users/{users} {

    // Check if existing email is same as you trying to write/read

      allow read, write : if resource.data.email == request.auth.token.email;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: @CodeKadiya Did you tried it ? It's working for me.

Comment: the thing is `resource` is always null